TcpClient connecting even though no TcpListener is running
I've got something happening I do not understand.
I have a laptop connected to my home office over a VPN with a 172.* IP address.  I have a system at the office that I remote into with a 10.* IP address.  I can ping each system from the other.
On my laptop, I have a C# program that creates a TcpClient on the 172.* address and connects to the 10.* IP address on port 9000.  On the remote system, I have a C# program that creates a TcpListener on the 10*. IP address, listening on port 9000.  If I run the TcpListener and then start the TcpClient, everything works as expected.
Here's where it gets weird for me.
If I don't start the TcpListener first, but just run the TcpClient program, a connection is still...immediately...established.  Opening Wireshark, I see the [SYN] [SYN/ACK] [RST/ACK] like I expect, and yet, the TcpClient shows in the code as connected, i.e., the Connected property shows as true.  But as soon as I try to read or write via the NetworkStream, I get an InvalidOperationException saying the operation is not allows on non-connected sockets.
How is the TcpClient connecting when there is no TcpListener, no server, running on the remote system?
Here's the simplified code.  As soon as the tcpClient.BeginConnect() call is made, the callback fires, and the connection is established...with no server running on the remote system.  If I try to read from the tcpClient, I get the exception mentioned above.
public void Connect(IPEndPoint localEndPoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint)
{
    var socket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

    socket.Bind(localEndPoint);

    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);

    this.tcpClient = new(localEndPoint.AddressFamily) { Client = socket };

    this.tcpClient.BeginConnect(remoteEndPoint.Address, remoteEndPoint.Port, this.ConnectCallback, remoteEndPoint);
}

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        this.tcpClient.EndConnect(ar);

        this.tcpStream = this.tcpClient.GetStream();

        this.Connected?.Raise(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // error handling
    }
}

EDIT
Alright.  I'm providing this simplified code snippet for reference.  This is a scratch project that I just ran on my laptop, which is VPN'd into my office network.  I've logged into the remote system via Remote Desktop.  The only app that is running on that system is Task Manager (not counting background processes).
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create TcpClient on local endpoint.
    var client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.x.x.x"), 0));

    // Block until the connection to the remote system is established.
    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.x.x.x"), 9000));

    // Read from the connected TcpClient instance.
    client.GetStream().Read(new byte[100], 0, 100);
}

The Connect() call immediately returns, indicating the connection was established.  When I call Read() on the underlying NetworkStream, I get an IOException saying "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..'  Trying different port numbers produces the same behavior.
Now, if I go to the remote system and start my server, listening on port 9000, the Connect() call again returns immediately.  However, this time, the Read() call blocks as expected, awaiting data from the remote end.
How is the Connect() call succeeding without the server (TcpListener) running on the other end?  I would expect it to block until the server is started.  Does Windows have some feature that will automatically accept and immediately close inbound connections when a server does not exist?  Is there third-party software (anti-virus, perhaps?) that might do this, too?  I'm just really confused how the connection is being accepted and closed when the my server app is not running.

It would be useful to see your client code

A Listener will accept multiple client connections (usually by default up to 100 client connections).  Looks like you may not be closing the listener.  Check from cmd,exe >Netstat -a on server and see the state of TCP port 9000.

Do you happen to run Trend Micro on the Listener machine? If so, try deactivating it and try again. I've seen two different "security suites" that will pretend to accept connections and then just close them more or less gracefully.

@KlausGütter edited my question to include some code.

@jdweng There is no listener running on port 9000 on that system.  The [RST, ACK] that I get back indicates as such, right?

@Fildor Not Trend Micro.  That system does use Trellix Endpoint Security, however.  Perhaps that's what's happening.

But why are you binding the socket manually? TcpClient will do all of that for you anyway. Why create the socket yourself?

I said a listener can have up to 100 connections.  The [RST, ACK] indicates one connection closed.  Not the Listener closing.  The Listener may not work properly after one connection closes.  The listener may be using events and not recognizing an event so a second connection may not complete a connection, but still may acknowledge a [SYN] with a [SYN/ACK]

Opening Wireshark, I see the [SYN] [SYN/ACK] [RST/ACK] like I expect. I would expect to see only a [SYN] packet coming from the client, without a SYN/ACK coming back from the listener. If you get a [SYN/ACK], you're connected!

It looks to me that your code is connecting and then immediately disconnecting. RST/ACK basically means a combination of ACK of the previous SYN/ACK to start the connection and RST to close. What are you actually doing with the connection, can you show more code?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Exactly.  How is the connection being established if I'm not running my server on the remote system?  There has to be something accepting the connection and then immediately closing it, but I have no idea how this is happening.

@Charlieface Once the connection happens, the ConnectCallback() is called.  I grab the NetworkStream and fire the Connected event, which causes the listening code to attempt to read from the "connected" socket.  This immediately fails because it rightly tells me the socket isn't connected.  How is the connection being established if I'm not actively running my server (TcpListener) on the remote system? What is the Window system doing to cause the connection to look like it's established?  I've never seen this happen before.

@jdweng I understand that listeners can accept numerous connections.  The point is, my listener is not running.  I was debugging and noticed the ConnectCallback() being called before I'd ever gone to start the server.  I just don't understand what Windows or some firewall software is doing under the hood to cause this to happen.

Thanks to all for the feedback.  I guess what I'm trying to figure out is if I'm insane or not.  I'm used to Connect() calls waiting until there's a server to receive and process the connection.  No server, no connection.  I'm not running my server.  What might be listening in the background on Windows or some third-party software that would be triggering the connection?  That's what I'm trying to understand.  Thanks again.

I'm just not sure this code is using the API correctly. Why are you creating your own socket, why not use the one TcpClient gives you? Where is the rest of the code you are describing, that tries to read from the socket?

Make sure you aren't registering the event ConnectCallback() before you start the client.

@charlieface Because the ReuseAddress option has to be set before the Bind() call.  There's no way I'm aware of to have the TcpClient do this.  So I configure the Socket the way I need it and then replace the once created by TcpClient with the one I create.
I'll modify to include the Read() logic, but that has nothing to do with the connection being established.  The Read() call only tells me that the connection isn't valid.

@jdweng I don't understand.  The ConnectCallback is passed as the callback function to the BeginConnect() call.

@all, updated my question to hopefully simplify the discussion.

Is your firewall running? Windows Firewall by default will drop the TCP connection if nothing is allowed on the port (so it simply won't connect), but if no firewall then by default it will allow the connection and immediately reset it. Some third party firewalls also incorrectly do this as well.

@Charlieface So if there is no firewall running, Windows accepts the connection and resets it automatically?  That would explain the [SYN],[SYN,ACK],[RST,ACK} I see in Wireshark, but it seems categorically wrong for the TcpClient to treat that as a connection in the same way as if the server had been running.  What I'm left to do is process the connection, attempt to read from it, and if I get no exception, then I know the connection has been established. That's not the way I understood the connection mechanism to work.  No server, no connection, is what I expected.

I found the issue.  The parameters for your connect method is using local and remote endpoints.  You are passing the method the remote endpoint and port number.

@jdweng.  I'm not following.  Both the Connect() and BeginConnect() calls on the TcpClient object require the remote IP address and port.  This exact same code (both examples) works as expected when the server is running on the remote system.

What does this code do? public void Connect(IPEndPoint localEndPoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint)  Is the port set? BeginConnect(remoteEndPoint.Address, remoteEndPoint.Port, this.ConnectCallback, remoteEndPoint);

@jdweng It creates a stream-based (TCP) Socket instance, sets a couple of properties, binds to port 9000 on the local system, wraps the Socket instance with a TcpClient instance, and then starts the connection process to the remote system.

Either, the endpoint at 10.x.x.x:9000 is listening and accepting TCP connections or you have an intermediary device that is masqurading and listening/responding on it's behalf.
TcpClient.Connect() will not return if the TCP three-way hand shake does not complete.
If you undertake a packet trace you will see the SYN/SYNACK/ACK TCP handshake.    If you believe that this is not coming from the actual endpoint, then you'll need to engage someone who understands your network to investigate what could be causing it.
But bottom line, something is responding to the SYN and the threeway handshake is completing.

Wireshark shows [SYN][SYN/ACK][RST/ACK]. I know the connection must be happening, but I have no idea how.  Once I start the server on that system, it connects fine and acts the way I expect.  When the server is not running, I expect the Connect() call to wait until I start the server.  This isn't happening.  Something on that system is accepting the connection and killing it.  And it doesn't matter the port number.  I suspect virus software or firewall, but I don't know how to find that out.

You can see which process owns the TCP connection on the server using "netstat -o".  But interestingly that's not a valid connection, so it won't even show.  I am actually surprised that TcpClient doesn't throw an exception, because the connection actually failed.

@MattDavis so the client is sending RST/ACK? Or the server seems to? I assume you're working on the client. Some VPNs might stick themselves in the middle of TCP connections attempting to sped them up.
